# Combining promises into promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

For a list of ids I'd like to make some GETs. These are wrapped in a promise.

```
let ids = [1, 2, 3]
let promises = [];
for (id in ids) {
    promises.push(ApiService.get(url + id))
}
return promises
```

Now when calling promises.all on the result, the results are in order of creating them (1, 2, 3). Since this happens in some kind of API controller, I rather not have to return the "ids" along with the promises. But rather return something of a:

```
{1: PromiseofId1, 2: PromiseofId2, 3:PromiseofId3}
```

Maybe my way of thinking is flawed, I am open for suggestions.

Comment: When i see an array and `for ... in` used together, i get goosebumps.

Comment: @ASDFGerte why?

Comment: `Promise.all()` uses an array. Use the array `index`.. Best practice would be to structure the API so that whatever it returns, also identifies what it is, so the order won't matter to know what is what on the client.

Comment: @Gibor the array in his example could be `["lalala", null, undefined]`, it wouldn't change a thing. Also, if someone gets the great idea of adding an enumerable property to `Array.prototype`, things get really nasty.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thank you for your comment, in this case I just wanted to show something quickly but you are correct. Reason I wrote it down like this cause in the original code I iterated over keys in an object, lateron swapped to Object.keys.

Comment: @Gibor Apart from also including enumerated values on the prototype, the specification of `for ... in` also does not require to loop in order. That depends on how the browser is coded. Most browsers will do so, but this is not guaranteed. So in case of an array it's not 100% certain that array element [0] will be handled first and this can lead to hard to find bugs. A normal `for ( let i = ....` loop and `array.forEach()` do not have this problem. See the MDN docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the order, you can reassociate them afterwards.

```
let ids = [1, 2, 3]
let promises = [];
for (id in ids) {
    promises.push(ApiService.get(url + id))
}
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    const data = {};
    results.forEach( (value, index) => { data[ ids[index] ] = value } );
    return data;
});
```

Comment: Albertos comment is correct also, choosing this one for readability in the team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build an object that maps each id into a `Promise` object. See this example, that has strings instead of Promises so you can see the output by running the snippet:

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3]
let promises = ids.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: `ApiService${cur}`}), {});

console.log(promises);
```

In your case, you can have this:

```
let ids = [1, 2, 3]
let promises = ids.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: ApiService.get(url + id)}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this.

```
async function getData(){
  const ids = [1, 2, 3]
  const promises = ids.map(id => ApiService.get(url + id))
  const responses = await Promise.all(promises)
  // Read whatever data from the response
  return responses.reduce((accumulator, response, index) => {
    accumulator[index + 1] = response.data
  }, {})
}

// Call it from an async function like this.
const dataMap = await getData()
// Returns {1:data1, 2:data2, ... }
```